# I am having this TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType' in Django code

Tags: python

Am using fusion chart to create a histogram below is the code for my data source, the line in bold throws a dataType error, which I have searched everywhere to find to no avail.

```
datasource['data'] = []
for item in get_employee_overall_performance(emp_id, year, period):
    data1, data2 = {}, {}
    data1['label'], data2['label'] = '% Achieved','% Unachieved'
    **data1['value'], data2['value'] = item['score']/item['weight']*100, 100 -item['score']/item['weight']*100**
    datasource['data'].append(data1)
    datasource['data'].append(data2)

doughnut3d = FusionCharts("doughnut3d", "ex3" , "100%", "400", "emp-perf-donutchart", "json", datasource)
```

Comment: "django" tag removed, there's nothing specific here.  And the source of your error is simple: for at least one of your `item`, both `item["score"]` and `item["weight"]` are `None` (the Python object for 'null') - which can't be used in a division, for very obvious reasons. FWIW I'm __very__ surprised you couldn't find anything on the net about your error...

Comment: I am quite new to python and Django, so it is sometimes to figure out the answers provided by other users with different scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty simple error. In the line,

```py
data1['value'], data2['value'] = item['score']/item['weight']*100, 100 -item['score']/item['weight']*100
```

you are making a division and during that process, python is finding any one or more than one value to be `None`.

As you mentioned in the title of your question, this is a `Django` app and I am assuming the values on which you are performing the operation is directly or indirectly obtained from the user. So, to avoid such errors, you might want to consider performing a sanity check on the user inputs.